# Display images from concat mysql & php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display some images inside php.

```
<?php
    $sql1 = "
   SELECT data1.id
         , data1.profileid
         , data1.Employer
         , CONCAT('[',GROUP_CONCAT(data2.Url),']') Url 
      FROM database1 data1 
      LEFT 
      JOIN database2 data2 
          ON data1.id = data2.employerid 
     WHERE data1.profileid = '$session' 
     GROUP 
        BY data1.id
         , data1.profileid
         , data1.Employer";
        $resultEmployer = mysqli_query($db, $sql1) or die;

    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultEmployer) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultEmployer))
            {
               $employer    .= "" . $row['Employer'] . "";
               $employer    .= "" . $row['Url'] . "";
                    }
            }
    ?>
```

The output from the database inside php is:

- Jake
  ['https://example.com/jake1.jpg,https://example.com/jake2.jpg,https://example.com/jake3.jpg']
- Stephanie
  ['https://example.com/stephanie1.jpg,https://example.com/stephanie2.jpg,https://example.com/stephanie3.jpg']

I don't know how to put these links (from the CONCAT in MYSQL) inside an img-tag to display the images and not the url(s) itself. I tried this without success:

```html
<?php
$employer .= "<img src=" . $row['Url'] . "";
?>
```

Who can help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You want the output of your image tag to look like this:

```
<img src="THEURL">
```

Right now you're not putting the url in quotes or closing the tag. You'd need to do something like this

```
$employer .= '<img src="' . $row['Url'] . '">';
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work. The problem is the string. The string contains multiple links, like in my first post. I can't put these whole string inside an img-tag. Maybe I can display the images one-by-one with Javascript?